# jquery ajax post array returns empty

Tags: php, jquery, post

Post a JSON.stringified array with the following format:

```
[{"AccountNumber":1630,"AccountName":"text1","Balance":83,"AccountType":6,"AccountTypeDescription":"text2"},{"AccountNumber":1930,"AccountName":"text3","Balance":1444492.39,"AccountType":9,"AccountTypeDescription":"text4"}]
```

On the php end it returns an empty array. What is missing?

JQuery coded:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'url.php',
type: 'post',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(resp.responseJSON.Data),
success: function (data2) {
console.log(data2);
},
});
```

Php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to extract json string from request

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) instead of print_r and check what you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line has `undefined` error:

```
data: JSON.stringify(resp.responseJSON.Data)
```

If your array variable name is `resp`:

```
var resp=[{"AccountNumber":1630,"AccountName":"text1","Balance":83,"AccountType":6,"AccountTypeDescription":"text2"},{"AccountNumber":1930,"AccountName":"text3","Balance":1444492.39,"AccountType":9,"AccountTypeDescription":"text4"}]
```

Then try:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'url.php',
type: 'post',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(resp),
success: function (data2) {
console.log(data2);
}
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove JSON.stringify in data part and put the response in an array.
Like,
var urdata=[];
urdata.push(resp.responseJSON.Data);

In Ajax call :
data:urdata

Comment: Not if sending as `'application/json'`

Comment: I don't agree. Either you set content type or send serialized data

Comment: Right...but OP is already setting contentType. So, if you want them to serialize instead you need to clarify and not mix the two

Comment: Op? So, better if he doesn't serialize. Also, he wants the data in an array, but he is not sending in an array

Comment: OP = Original Post .... the data shown sure looks like array to me

Comment: If he is getting the data in an array from resp.responseJSON.Data then he doesn't need to put in an array again. just removing stringify should work